# Simple React component not rendering

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have created a simple React component which displays another react component. But it doesn't render in browser :

```
class Home extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <map/>
      </div>   
    );
  }
}

var map = React.createClass({
   render: function() {
      return (
          <div id="map-canvas">
            <span>hello</span>
          </div>
      );
    }
});
```

I'm expecting the `hello` to show up on the screen, but nothing shows up and when I inspect the element all I can see is

```
<map data-reactid=".0.0"></map>
```

Can any one point our what might be wrong.

Answer (score 84, accepted):

JSX expects component tags to be capitalized. Otherwise, it will just create a DOM element with the provided tag. See [HTML Tags vs. React Components](https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/jsx-in-depth.html#html-tags-vs.-react-components).

`<map />` compiles to `React.createElement("map", {});` while `<Map />` compiles to `React.createElement(Map, {});`.

Just rename `map` to `Map` and you're good.

Comment: well that gives another error `Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'toUpperCase' of undefined ReactDefaultInjection.js:53`

Comment: Make sure that `Map` is correctly defined in the context of your `App::render` method. Also, be aware that in ES6, `Map` is a standard built-in object, so you might want to rename your component to something else.

Comment: Ok.. I renamed it to `MyMap` but still the same error.

Comment: Moving `MyMap` above `Home` resolved the issue. Thanks anyways .. :)

Comment: This behaviour is not at all intuitive I was expecting <myComponent> and <MyComponent> do the same, but I can imagine why is behaving like this. kudos for your help.

Answer (score 1):

Just make sure that variable which you declare for creating components starts with a uppercase:-Just Like this

```
var Map = React.createClass({
 //Your Code here

});
```