# React Bootstrap Components not displaying

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs, ecmascript-6, babeljs

I'm trying to test out the carousel but when I load the page it is blank.

I installed react bootstrap with npm.

The carousal code is from https://react-bootstrap.github.io/components.html#media-content. I looked at my web console and I don't have any warnings or errors either.

carousal.js

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import {Carousel} from 'react-bootstrap';
class carousel extends Component {
    render() {
        return (
            <Carousel>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src={require('./images/cs_logo.png')}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>First slide label</h3>
                        <p>Nulla vitae elit libero, a pharetra augue mollis interdum.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src={require('./images/cs_logo.png')}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Second slide label</h3>
                        <p>Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
                <Carousel.Item>
                    <img width={900} height={500} alt="900x500" src={require('./images/cs_logo.png')}/>
                    <Carousel.Caption>
                        <h3>Third slide label</h3>
                        <p>Praesent commodo cursus magna, vel scelerisque nisl consectetur.</p>
                    </Carousel.Caption>
                </Carousel.Item>
            </Carousel>
        );
    }
}

export default carousel;
```

index.js

```
import React from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import carousel from './carousal';

ReactDOM.render(<carousel/>,document.getElementById('root'));
```

index.html

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">

<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/latest/css/bootstrap.min.css">  
    <title>title</title>
</head>

<body>
<header>
<div id="nav"></div>
</header>
<div id="root" style="text-align: center; float: none"></div>
</body>

</html>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Found the solution. It is not Bootstrap related but rather how I was exporting and naming my components.

Components need to capitalized as stated here.  [Simple React component not rendering](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29850247/simple-react-component-not-rendering)

Answer (score 1):

Did you include js files to html file?

```
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.6/react-bootstrap.js" > </srcipt>

<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react-bootstrap/0.30.6/react-bootstrap.js" > </srcipt>
```

Comment: I tried adding it and now I get this error in console
"react-bootstrap.js:2037 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'PropTypes' of undefined(…)exports.__esModule @ react-bootstrap.js:2037__webpack_require__ @ react-bootstrap.js:30exports.__esModule @ react-bootstrap.js:430__webpack_require__ @ react-bootstrap.js:30exports.__esModule @ react-bootstrap.js:62__webpack_require__ @ react-bootstrap.js:30exports.__esModule @ react-bootstrap.js:50(anonymous function) @ react-bootstrap.js:53webpackUniversalModuleDefinition @ react-bootstrap.js:9(anonymous function) @ react-bootstrap.js:10"

Answer (score 1):

Add this in index.js file

```
import 'bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css';
```

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score 0):

Add the CDN link in index.html.
Although you found it this would help others.

```
<link
rel="stylesheet"
href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/4.2.1/css/bootstrap.min.css"
integrity="sha384-GJzZqFGwb1QTTN6wy59ffF1BuGJpLSa9DkKMp0DgiMDm4iYMj70gZWKYbI706tWS"
crossorigin="anonymous"/>
```

or add this in app.css

```
@import "bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```